# How to get related data for each record?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I have the following two tables, with the common variable being `post_id`:

`Posts` table:

```
+---------+---------+-------+---------+
| post_id | user_id | title | content |
+---------+---------+-------+---------+
|       1 |       1 | Hello | World   |
+---------+---------+-------+---------+
```

`Tags` table:

```
+--------+---------+----------+
| tag_id | post_id | tag_name |
+--------+---------+----------+
|      1 |       1 | Tag1     |
|      2 |       1 | Tag2     |
|      3 |       1 | Tag3     |
+--------+---------+----------+
```

Here is my current `Post` model, nothing out of the ordinary:

```
class Post extends Eloquent {

    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'posts';

    /**
     * The primary key of the table.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $primaryKey = 'post_id';

    /**
     *  The post id.
     *
     * @var integer
     */
    protected $post_id = 0;

    /**
     *  The user id of the post.
     *
     * @var integer
     */
    protected $user_id = 0;

    /**
     *  The title of the post.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $title = '';

    /**
     *  The content of the post.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $content = '';

}
```

And here is my Controller:

```
class IndexController extends BaseController
{

    /**
     * Show a list of post.
     *
     * @return view
     */
    public function showIndex()
    {
        $posts = Post::all();

        return View::make('index', array('posts' => $posts));
    }

}
```

My question is, how would I, in addition to showing the posts in the view, get the related tags for each post.

For example, using the above tables, `post_id = 1` has 3 related tags in the `Tags` table: `Tag1`, `Tag2`, and `Tag3`.

How would I get the relating tags for each post using the `post_id` and then be able to use them in the view?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work

Model:

```
class Tag extends Eloquent {
    // other stuff
    public function tags(){
        return $this->hasMany('Tag');
    }
}
```

Query

```
Post::with('tags')->get();
```

Access tags with loop

```
foreach($post->tags as $tag){
    echo $post->tag_name;
}
```

Comment: How would I then access the tag data in a view?

Comment: Last question, how would I loop through the tags so that I can display them one by one?

Answer (score 0):

You should first [define a many to many](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#many-to-many) relation between your posts and tags, then you would

```
 $posts = Posts::with('tags')->get();
```

Comment: How would I then access the tag data in a view?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Eloquent to establish relationships between your models. This would be an example of that:

```
class Post extends Eloquent {

    public function tags()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Tag');
    }

}
```

You could get then do something like this to get the tags associated with a Post

```
Post::find(1)->tags();
```

You also need to add `tag_id` to your `post` table to setup this relationship properly. On your `tags` table to I would reference the `id` instead of having `tag_id`.

Comment: Why add `tag_id` to the `Posts` table, when the relation isn't needed?